# Regular Expression - How can I match all numbers less than or equal to Twenty Four?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm somewhat new to regular expressions and am writing validation for a quantity field where regular expressions need to be used.

How can I match all numbers less than or equal to 24?

I tried

```
var pat = /^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$/;
```

But that only matches 1-24. Is there a simple way to match all possible numbers less than or equal to 24?

Comment: Do yo want to match negative numbers too?

Comment: is the quantity field not numeric? function `Number` might help.

Comment: Your regex actually matches 1-36 . . . but anyway, you need to describe your rules much more precisely than just "all numbers less than or equal to 24", since that really sounds like it should mean 1-24 . . .

Comment: Agree. Are arbitrarily big negative numbers supposed to pass this regex expression? Say, -1, -24, and -5060000.

Comment: For only positive numbers [`^(2[0-4])|(^[01]?[0-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/eA8vQ4/1) [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a5v7hjs3/)

Comment: Can't use just check if the value is <= 24 and >= 1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I won't recommend you to use regex just to check if a number is between the range. To compare the numbers comparison operators should be used.

```
if (number >= 0 && number <= 24)
```

However, if this is not feasible/possible, you can use regex.

---

You can also use

```
^(2[0-4]|[01]?[0-9])$
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eA8vQ4/2)

**Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of line anchor
2. `2[0-4]`: Matches `2` followed by any number between 0 to 4 - Matches 20-24
3. `|`: OR condition in regex
4. `[01]?[0-9]`: `[01]?`: Matches 0 or 1 optionally. `[0-9]`: Matches any number exactly once in the range 0 to 9 - Matches 0-19

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a5v7hjs3/)

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="(2[0-4]|[01]?[0-9])" />
```

---

You can use following regex

```
^(2[0-4])|(^[01]?[0-9])$
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eA8vQ4/1)

Comment: Trying to modify it to take arbitrary negative numbers and leading zeros: `var pattern = /(?:(^-0*\d+$)|((^0*2[0-4]$)|(^0*1?\d$)))/;` - https://regex101.com/r/vA8rY2/3

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[0-9]|[1][0-9]|2[0-4])$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/3

Comment: @Tushar it will match `0` now :P